# How to use asp.net mvc web api when using the rest service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an webapi2.0 ,through webapi i'm hitting another restful service which is implemented in java.

actually i have only one concerns here how can implement the multi threading through webapi because when i'm hitting the service then some of my static class and other related data are not populating .

can any one help me regarding to the rest services.

Here is my code:

```
public HttpResponseMessage ListEmployee() 
{ 
    Employee emp = new Employee{}; 
    List<Employee> EmployeeList = new List<Employee>{};
    var emp = emp.getlist(); 
    foreach(var item in emp)
    { 
        var details = emp.getDetails(item.id); 
    } 
    return WebApiResponse.Success<List<APICreatePatientModel>>(EmployeeList); 
}
```

Comment: public HttpResponseMessage ListEmployee()
        {
Employee emp = new Employee{};
List<Employee> EmployeeList = new List<Employee>{};
var emp = emp.getlist();
foreach(var item in emp){

var details = emp.getDetails(item.id);
}

return WebApiResponse.Success<List<APICreatePatientModel>>(EmployeeList);
}

Comment: Hey @Martin Brandl, i have shared my code pattern and i want hit multiple  employee at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

It might help you,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Send an AJAX request
    $.getJSON(apiUrl)
        .done(function (data) {
            // On success, 'data' contains a list of Employee.
            $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                // TODO as per you!.                    
            });
        });
});
```

For more detail, you can go links

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/344078/ASP-NET-WebAPI-Getting-Started-with-MVC-and-WebAP
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-web-api.html

Comment: sorry that's not answer of question because i'm using the webapi and can i hit multiple employee details at same time through threading but i had check that also it's not working.